# Enclose variable in double quotes Ansible (gcdns_record TXT record_data)

Tags: ansible, yaml

When i set my `record_data` like this:

record_data: "{{ some-var }}"

I get this error msg `TXT record_data must be enclosed in double quotes, got: CQ5fc59u-izwcu8_PlI2HlvfUT73bH2VnMU_jW3B5hY`

Normal because the doc says `Individual string record_data for TXT records must be enclosed in double quotes` (see [doc here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/gcdns_record_module.html))

So i tried this

record_data: "\"{{ some-var }}\""

The task executed well, no error, but i didn't get ride of the `\`. I got something like this as record_data `"\"*****\""` (***** is the actual value of `some-var`)

So my question is, how do i manage to get my variable value enclosed in double quotes ?

Or, the question may be: how do i set a variable as TXT value while creating a record with `gcdns_record` ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrap it in another quote type. Single quotes in this case:

```
record_data: '"{{ some-var }}"'
```

Comment: Actually my `some-var` was a litte complicated (challenge_result.challenge_data[domain]['dns-01'].resource_value) this is why i couldn't use the simple quotes. But finally i extracted the long variable to a simple variable and i enclosed it with simple quotes as u suggested and it works fine.

Thank u @techraf